# How do I make my navbar work cross-browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="#service" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">SOFTWASHING</a></li>
 <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">NANO-TECH</a></li>
 <li><a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have been struggling for a while trying to get my navbar to work. For some reason it doesn't work on chrome or android.

Im not sure if its a coding issue or if I need to update my scrollTo libraries. Im at a loss and out of ideas. I have read through the posts on here and sometimes updating the libraries can fix the problem. I am a novice at this and wouldn't know where to start or how to do this.

If somebody could help me, that would be great. The website is www.suresealservices.co.uk

Thank you in advance`

HOME

SERVICES

SOFTWASHING

NANO-TECH

COMMERCIAL

CONTACT

`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi Paulie_D. Thank you for you message. I didn't include any code as Im not sure if the problem is the code itself or down to the libraries I am using for my site. I can post the code if its required to keep my question live and accessible for other members to view and comment on.

Comment: @ChrisLawler — Part of the point of creating a [mcve] is that you will discover that as part of the process.

Comment: Hi Quentin. That's the problem, I have never coded a website before and I have used a template site to build my page. I wouldn't know what I am looking for although I would love to learn. I suppose this is the down side of using a template.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to have to put in some more legwork into actually understanding what you are dealing with. A template is a good start, but to debug, there is no other way than to get into the nitty gritty and learn about what you have on your hands. Your first step should be to find and include all the relevant HTML for your header, then the CSS rules that apply to your header, and then any JQuery that applies to your header. Then we might be able to help.

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="#service" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">SOFTWASHING</a></li>
 <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">NANO-TECH</a></li>
 <li><a href="#portfolio" class="smoothScroll">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Hope the above makes sense

Comment: The sections of the code in capital have been changed from the template standard text to show what I want on my website. As per @cdpautsch post earlier, it now makes sense what you say. I checked the css file and it still shows the old text from the template. Does this need to be changed to match the text in capital above?

Comment: You should be adding code with proper code formatting to your original post. That is indecipherable in comments. Editing your original post is the proper way to add information, while comments are for discussion.

Comment: Im trying my best here. Anyway, code should now be added to the post.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the links to go to locations on the page, you are going to have to add the `id` attribute to each of those locations. For instance, you have a link `<a href="#Contacts">Contacts</a>`. You should go to the header of the Contacts section and mark it up as `<h2 id="Contacts">Contacts</h2>`. Easy peasy.  :-)

Comment: thank you for your input. I am going to try this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I don't get it. It works perfectly on Edge, Firefox and Safari but not on Chrome or Android.